# Vertical centering <a> with glyphicon on Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using **Twitter Bootstrap 3**, and I don't have any additional CSS file.
I have the following code somewhere in my HTML page:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Task"/>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="textarea" class="form-control" placeholder="Descr."/>
    </div>
    <a ng-click="addTask()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></a>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `+` is not well centered. I would like to vertical align it with my inputs.
I suppose it is something simple, but I have not yet found a good solution ...

Can you help me finding how I can vertical center this `<a>` ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: You need to add top margin for +.

Comment: I tried `<a ng-click="addTask()" style="margin-top:-15px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></a>` it does not move anything. I also tried with margin-bottom

Comment: margin-top should have positive value.

Comment: I tried it by having margin-top:5px and its working for me.

Comment: I saw, @luk492 had post an answer few minutes ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this(change the px to your liking)

```
<a ng-click="addTask()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="margin-top:15px;"></a>
```

Comment: I've tried with a negative value of margin-top, and it does not do anything ... But, it seems that your code works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `vertical-align: middle;`:

```
<a ng-click="addTask()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" 
   style="vertical-align: middle;"></a>
```

Comment: @Mistalis Is it not because it is sat outside of the div column?

Comment: The code I use is that which is written in my question. I have not changed since then :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<a ng-click="addTask()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="display: inline-block; margin-top:15px;"></a>
```